# How to disable cgridview view button or setting visiability to false

Tags: gridview, yii, visible, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

can some buddy please suggest how to disable view button on cgridview widget and how to add more button like active..

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'customer-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
       'id',
       'first_name',
           'last_name',
       'club.club_name',
       array(
         'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                     'updateButtonUrl' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/customer/editmember1",array("id" => $data->primaryKey))',
                     'updateButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/edit.jpg',
                     'deleteButtonUrl' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/customer/delete",array("id" => $data->primaryKey))',
                     'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/delete.jpg', 
                     'viewButton' => array('visiable' => false), 
            ),

              ),   
               ));
```

Comment: [There's a documentation for a reason](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/)

Comment: +1 for some buddy! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the '[template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#template-detail)' property do show only your desired buttons:

```
'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
           'template' => '{update}{delete}',
                 'updateButtonUrl' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/customer/editmember1",array("id" => $data->primaryKey))',
                 'updateButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/edit.jpg',
                 'deleteButtonUrl' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/customer/delete",array("id" => $data->primaryKey))',
                 'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/delete.jpg', 
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks "sucotronic" it works very well, i am new to yii so having some difficulties thanks again.

Comment: @Coder you're welcome. Yii is a greatly documented and have nice tutorial to start with it. Hope you enjoy as much as me and build great webpages :)

Comment: Thanks @sucotronic this was so helpful!

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty simple. For example I have the following grid where I have disabled the Update and Delete buttons. Only the view button is has visible=>true

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'activity-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'employee_id',
    'vehicle_id',
    'radio_id',
    'aed_id',
    'laptop_id',
    /*
    'checked_out_on',
    'checked_in_on',
    */
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{update}{view}{delete}',
                    'buttons'=>array(
                    'update'=>array(
                            'visible'=>'false',
                    ),
                    'view'=>array(
                            'visible'=>'true',
                    ),
                    'delete'=>array(
                            'visible'=>'false',
    ),
```

),

```
    ),
),
```

));

Answer (score 2):

```
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                    'template' => '{update}',
                     'updateButtonUrl' =>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/post/update",array("id" => $data->primaryKey))',
                    'updateButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/assets/aed78a8d/gridview/update.png',
```

Comment: Note : aed78a8d this value may be different

Comment: array(
             'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
             'template' => '{update} {delete}',
         ),